# R Function to extract values greater than x

Tags: r

I am running a simulation model and would like to know how to extract all values greater than 6 in this gamma distribution. Thank you!

```
cost <- 100
n_samp <-1000

gamma<-rgamma(n_samp,2,0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also subset the array `gamma` with a logical vector:

```
gt6_values = gamma[gamma > 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subset` from base R to get just the values greater than 6.

`subset(gamma, gamma > 6)`